# Porquê login pelo google plus no angularjs não funciona correctamente?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app móvel e tenho opção para fazer login pelo google plus tenho o `controller` mas quando faço login e escolho a conta as informações não me são guardadas na `session.set` fiz seguindo este tuturial https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus já fiz o passo 1 do para configurar o android ele gerou um ficheiro que fiz com o `keytool` mas tambem nao sei onde ponho esse ficheiro mas quando faço login não bem informações da conta que esta a fazer `login` nem pede permissões.

**Controller**

```
.controller('LoginGoogle', function($http, $scope, sessionService, $ionicLoading) {
  // This method is executed when the user press the "Sign in with Google" button
  $scope.googleSignIn = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Aguarde...'
    });

    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {},
      function (user_data) {

        sessionService.set('user_id',user_data.userId);
        sessionService.set('nome',user_data.displayName);
        sessionService.set('user_foto',user_data.imageUrl);
        //sessionService.set('user_slug',userInfo.user_slug);

        $ionicLoading.hide();

        window.location = "#/app/home"
      },
      function (msg) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    );
  };
})
```

Ficheiro Gerado e feito download

```
google-services.json
```

Comment: Há mensagens de erro no console do chrome?